# C programming - difference between freeing a char ** filled with simple quotes and filled with double quotes - valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind, free, double-quotes, single-quotes

I'm trying to test the free function with this program

```
  char **tab;

  // allocation
  tab = malloc(5 * sizeof(char*));
  for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
    {
      tab[j] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
    }

  // FILL TAB FIRST WAY
  /*
  for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
    {
      for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
        {
          tab[j][i] = '@';
        }
    }
  */

  // FILL TAB SECOND WAY
  for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
    {
      tab[j] = "@@@@";
    }

  //free
  for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
    {
      free(tab[j]);
    }

  free(tab);
```

The first way to fill the tab (each character individually) returns no memory errors with valgrind whereas the second way (filling the tab line by line) do returns some memory errors.

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==447==     in use at exit: 20 bytes in 5 blocks
==447==   total heap usage: 6 allocs, 6 frees, 60 bytes allocated
==447==
==447== Searching for pointers to 5 not-freed blocks
==447== Checked 64,648 bytes
==447==
==447== LEAK SUMMARY:
==447==    definitely lost: 20 bytes in 5 blocks
==447==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==447==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==447==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==447==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==447== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==447==
==447== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==447==
==447== 5 errors in context 1 of 1:
==447== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==447==    at 0x4C2EDEB: free (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-
amd64-linux.so)
==447==    by 0x400607: main (test_malloc.c:35)
```

What is the explanation for that ?

Comment: `tab[j] = "@@@@";` do you know what you are doing here ?

Comment: Also, you're trying to fit 5 characters ("@@@@" and a NULL terminator) into 4-character memory blocks.

Comment: do you know what you are doing here ?             Not really in fact, I lack understanding of what's going on behind the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your second scenario, you've allocated memory using:

```
tab[j] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
```

Then overwritten the pointers with the address of `"@@@@"` (a string literal):

```
tab[j] = "@@@@";
```

So you've just:

1. Lost track of the `malloc`ed memory (what your `LEAK SUMMARY` states).
2. Attempted to `free()` a string literal (what your `ERROR SUMMARY` states).

---

If you want to properly copy `"@@@@"` into the memory, you could use [`strncpy()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/):

```
strncpy(tab[j], "@@@@", 4);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do `tab[j] = "@@@@"`. It is simply not valid. Or to the very least, it doesn't do what you think it does.

A correct way could be `strncpy(tab[j], "@@@@", 4)`

Answer (score 1):

When you do this

```
tab[j] = "@@@@";
```

you overwrite the allocation you did earlier

```
tab[j] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
```

The string `"@@@@"` was not allocated by your code, and not by `malloc()` anyway, that's an address in a static area that cannot be freed with `free()`.

Freeing such an address is Undefined Behavior.

Not that it matters with your code (since the allocated address is overwritten), but the `malloc()` allocation should be of 5 bytes to cope with the final `'\0'` of `"@@@@"`.

Answer (score 1):

This is assigning 4 bytes of memory to `tab[j]` which is space enough for 3 characters plus the NUL terminator

```
tab[j] = malloc(4 * sizeof(char));
```

This line is replacing the value of `tab[j]` with a string that hasn't been allocated with `malloc`. Your `free` a few lines down won't be freeing the memory you allocated and will do who knows what given it's being passed something that wasn't allocated.

```
tab[j] = "@@@@";
```

That second line should use `strcpy`, except as mentioned at the top of the answer, you're only allocating space for 3 characters and here, you're trying to store 4.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference in the following declarations

```
char s[4] = "@@@@";
```

and (an assignment expression also can be used instead of the declaration)

```
char *s = "@@@@";
```

In the first case the elements of the string literal `"@@@@"` are used to initialize the elements of the array. So the first declaration is equivalent to

```
char s[4] = { '@', '@', '@', '@' };
```

In the second case there is created a string literal with static storage duration that has the type `char[5]` (due to the appended terminating zero) and the address of the first character of the string literal is assigned to the pointer `s`.

You may imagine this declaration (or assignmnet expression )
the following way

```
static char unnamed_string_literal[5] = { '@', '@', '@', '@', '\0' };
char *s = &unnamed_string_literal[0];
```

or

```
char *s;
static char unnamed_string_literal[5] = { '@', '@', '@', '@', '\0' };
s = &unnamed_string_literal[0];
```

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

6 In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.78) The multibyte character sequence is then used to initialize **an array of static storage duration** and length just sufficient to contain the sequence. For character string literals, the array elements have type char, and are initialized with the individual bytes of the multibyte character sequence....

So in this code snippet

```
  for(int i=0 ; i<4 ; i++)
    {
      tab[j][i] = '@';`
    }
```

you filled "manually" the allocated memory with the character `'@'`.

However in this code snippet as the expression `tab[j]` has the type `char *`

```
for(int j=0 ; j<5 ; j++)
{
  tab[j] = "@@@@";
}
```

then you overwrote the previous values of the pointers that were addresses of the allocated memory with the addresses of the string literal or literals `"@@@@"`.

This leads to memory leaks as the addresses of the allocated memory are lost and you may not apply the function `free` for the pointers that now point to the memory with the static storage duration occupied by the string literal or literals (depending on how the compiler stores equal each other string literals).

Comment: Thank you, for the explanation. I understand better what's going on behind the code.